# I can't move items in viewDidAppear in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm having the issue where I have a UIView that displays no internet connection. I want it to dive out of the way when the view is loaded so as not to be seen. It should pop back up and go away when connections are either on and off..The notifier is working and if the connection goes on and off it will move or remove the banner. However when the view first loads it doesn't move the UIView out of the way.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.actOnSpecialNotification(_:)), name: "ReachabilityChangedNotification", object: nil)
       print("viewappeard")
        self.unableBox.center.y  -= view.bounds.height

    }


    func actOnSpecialNotification(note:NSNotification){
        let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

        if reachability.isReachable() {
            self.unableBox.center.y  -= view.bounds.height
            print(self.unableBox.center.y)
            print(view.bounds.height)
            if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
                print("Reachable via WiFi")
            } else {
                print("Reachable via Cellular")
            }
        } else {
            self.unableBox.center.y  = view.bounds.height/2
            print(self.unableBox.center.y)
            print(view.bounds.height)
            print("Network not reachable")
        }



        }
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout for unableBox? Is it an IB outlet or is it initialized in code?

Comment: IBoutlet however the actOnSpecialNotification function is able to move it around fine.